# Custom Application logs in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I have deployed a custom web application in WSO2 API Manager. However i used my own log4j.jar instead of WSO2 APIM log4j.jar.

Im not seeing the logs in default wso2carbon.logs. Can anyone please tell me where my logs will be saved/directed.

Comment: What do you mean your won log4j? Where did you copy your jar?

Comment: i added log4j.jar in /lib folder within my .war file